# C++ long double bigger "safe" whole number

Tags: c++, numbers

IEEE 754 numbers are not uniformly spaced, the larger the numbers, the bigger the difference between two consecutive representable numbers.
I have that the size of my long double with C++ is 16 bytes. So what is the bigger "safe" whole number "n" that can be represented with this type?.
I call it "safe" if n - 1 is possible to represent but  n + 1 not.

Comment: All large representable values of an IEEE floating-point type are whole numbers.

Comment: Thanks @AnT, you are right, but i just updated the question :), happens that n - 1 has to be possible to represent.

Comment: @JoseLuisPalacios does n - 2 need to be possible to represent?

Comment: @user2079303 yes, but you can assume if n - 1 is possible to represent, n - 2 is possible too

Comment: That assumption doesn't hold for negatives, but it seems that the question is about positives.

Answer (score 3):

The IEEE 754 standard defines the parameters of various numerical types:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754
for long doubles which are 128 bits long, the mantissa (the part of the floating point number that contains the significant digits) is 113 bits so it can represent integers with full precision up to 2^113 - 1.  It can represent floating point numbers which are larger, but you start losing precision beyond that because the lower order numbers just get rounded.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you're asking for which is the largest contiguous precisely representable integer. It is exactly:

```
std::pow(std::numeric_limits<long double>::radix, std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits)
```

or expressed in math: radix<sup>digits</sup> where (quoted from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits))

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix` is the base of the number system used in the representation of the type. It is 2 for all binary numeric types, but it may be, for example, 10 for IEEE 754 decimal floating-point types ...
>
> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` is the number of digits in base-radix that can be represented by the type T without change. ... For floating-point types, this is the number of digits in the mantissa

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is the number i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can get a lot of information using [`<limits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits). For example:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  auto p = std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_digits10;
  std::cout << "Max Long Double: "
            << std::setprecision(p)
            << std::setw(p + 7)
            << std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()
            << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
Max Long Double: 1.18973149535723176502e+4932
```

Comment: Thanks, but pitifully: (numeric_limits<long double>::max() == numeric_limits<long double>::max() - 1.0) is true. So numeric_limits<long double>::max() is not safe :(

Comment: What else did you expect? The next number after `1.18973149535723176502e+4932` toward zero is `1.18973149535723176496e+4932`. That's just how floating point arithmetic works.

Comment: It turns out that `n - 1` has to be possible to represent. The next number after `1.18973149535723176502e+4932` toward zero (`1.18973149535723176496e+4932`) is not `1.18973149535723176502e+4932 - 1.0`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For an IEEE double you can have up to 53 digits in the significand, so 2^53  is the maximum integer that fits (9,007,199,254,740,992). For long double, it depends on how it is represented. If it is an extended-precision, 80-bit number with 64 bits in the significand, then it is 2^64 (18,446,744,073,709,551,616).

Comment: The answer of @user2079303 describes how to use `<limits>` to inquire size of the significand.

Comment: Thanks, 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 is the number i was looking for.